# storing file in ROOT directory of apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, file-io

I want to store file in the ROOT Directory of Apache Tomcat server through java code so How to do this, because currently I am getting a context path which comes like `c:\\.....\selfprov` so I ma doing  `contextPath + File.seperator + "ROOT"`  but it doesn't store the file inside "ROOT" directory i think i need some permission to store the fiule inside ROOT directory but  i did that but still its not storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this sample read this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm  it has

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
  factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
```